# Delete User from Back-end not apply, Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, user-account

We use Magento 2.3.3 and I tried to delete user from backEnd (admin panel). 
Go to System > Permission > All Users > select the user that I want to delete, click on "Delete User" button, enter the admin password,  and got a message "You deleted the user.".

I still see the user in the list grid and still I found it in Data Base...

Any idea, why it is not delete the user from DataBase and BackEnd?

Thanks

Comment: Any error or else you found if system.log or exception.log?

Comment: I saw only under exceptio.log:temando.CRITICAL: "accountId" is required. Enter and try again. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\InputException(code: 0): \"accountId\" is required. Enter and try again. at /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/test.froggabio.com/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/InputException.php:91)"} []

Comment: any more idea, why is happen?

Comment: Is it default magento? As I did not have this kind of error.

Comment: We have magento 2.3.3 with Porto theme... looks like some issue from our side, but no option to see where is the issue...